# Stack on Stripe Terminal Reade with bellow images

Tags: terminal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

[WisePosE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApWUy.png)

I am using Stripe SDK's latest version (2.22.0) and continuously getting this error in several readers.

is there any solution regarding this? I am doing any implementation faults or it's getting from stripe SDK internal error.  please help me

```
{"errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_SDK_ERROR","errorMessage":"Currently processing transaction from different integration mode","detailMessage":"Currently processing transaction from different integration mode","stackTrace":[{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.CrpcResponseExtensions","fileName":"CrpcResponseExtensions.kt","lineNumber":20,"methodName":"withJackrabbitResponse"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.IpReaderController","fileName":"IpReaderController.kt","lineNumber":192,"methodName":"onActivateReader"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.RemoteReaderController","fileName":"RemoteReaderController.kt","lineNumber":46,"methodName":"activateReader"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.DefaultProxyRemoteReaderController$onActivateReader$1","fileName":"ProxyRemoteReaderController.kt","lineNumber":86,"methodName":"invoke"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.DefaultProxyRemoteReaderController$onActivateReader$1","fileName":"ProxyRemoteReaderController.kt","lineNumber":85,"methodName":"invoke"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.DefaultProxyRemoteReaderController","fileName":"ProxyRemoteReaderController.kt","lineNumber":250,"methodName":"withCurrentController"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.DefaultProxyRemoteReaderController","fileName":"ProxyRemoteReaderController.kt","lineNumber":245,"methodName":"withCurrentController$default"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.DefaultProxyRemoteReaderController","fileName":"ProxyRemoteReaderController.kt","lineNumber":85,"methodName":"onActivateReader"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.remotereadercontrollers.RemoteReaderController","fileName":"RemoteReaderController.kt","lineNumber":46,"methodName":"activateReader"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.resourcerepository.RemoteReaderResourceRepository","fileName":"RemoteReaderResourceRepository.kt","lineNumber":48,"methodName":"activateReader"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.resourcerepository.ProxyResourceRepository$activateReader$1","fileName":"ProxyResourceRepository.kt","lineNumber":52,"methodName":"invoke"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.resourcerepository.ProxyResourceRepository$activateReader$1","fileName":"ProxyResourceRepository.kt","lineNumber":51,"methodName":"invoke"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.resourcerepository.ProxyResourceRepository","fileName":"ProxyResourceRepository.kt","lineNumber":147,"methodName":"withCurrentRepository"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.resourcerepository.ProxyResourceRepository","fileName":"ProxyResourceRepository.kt","lineNumber":51,"methodName":"activateReader"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.terminalsession.TerminalSession","fileName":"TerminalSession.kt","lineNumber":503,"methodName":"activateReader$terminalsession_release"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.terminalsession.TerminalSession$ConnectReaderOperation","fileName":"TerminalSession.kt","lineNumber":1596,"methodName":"execute"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.terminalsession.TerminalSession$ExternalOperation","fileName":"TerminalSession.kt","lineNumber":1004,"methodName":"run$terminalsession_release"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.terminalsession.TerminalSession","fileName":"TerminalSession.kt","lineNumber":863,"methodName":"enqueueOperation$lambda$6"},{"declaringClass":"com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.terminalsession.TerminalSession","lineNumber":0
```

Comment: From the error message, it's likely you have a mixed of integration. For example, mixed usage of [server-driven](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/collect-payment?terminal-sdk-platform=server-driven) and [Android](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/collect-payment?terminal-sdk-platform=android) integrations. You should only use one of them.

Comment: can't I use both on one build?

Comment: No, you can only use one type of integration.